# Display the Local Date and Time as Year-Month-Day Hour-Minute-Second in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to create a variable that holds a formatted date display in JavaScript.  What I want is for the value to be set as Year-Month-Day Hour-Minute-Second.  So far this is what I have.

The toJSON method changes the timezone and I want it to represent my local time.  That is why I added the getTimezoneOffset code.

```
var date = new Date(Date.now() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60)).toJSON().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/:/g, '-').split('.')[0];

console.log(date);  // 2014-05-23 22-24-26
```

Is there a simpler or more appropriate way to get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I like to use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) for dealing with the many issues with JavaScript dates and times. It allows you to:

```
moment()        //now, whatever the local time is
   .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss') // "2014-05-23 21-48-11"
```

Simples :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try `toLocaleString()`, for example:

```
var d = new Date().toLocaleString(); // 5/24/2014 3:11:16 AM
```

But to format the date you may try something like this (or other ways):

```
var d, t;
d = new Date();
d = (d.toLocaleString()).split(' ');
t = d[1];
d = d[0].split('/');
d = d[2] + '-' + d[1] + '-' + d[0] + ' ' + t;
```

[You may like this.](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)

Comment: Most browsers, including Safari on MacOS, `.toLocaleDateString()` returns `mm/dd/yyyy`, but on iOS, all browsers return `dd/mm/yyyy` instead... so that's fun.